# How can I disable the serial port SAK option on Linux using userspace API?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I have an embedded linux setup generated using buildroot. As part of my application I have a dedicated thread that opens the serial port (/dev/ttyS0) for the purposes of listening for and replying to modbus messages. It works fine, but when my target device is connected to my host development machine, whenever I shutdown my dev machine, something is being sent over the serial port that is killing my process on the target. In this case I believe that it is the SAK (secure attention key) being received which results in SAK kernel messages and process being killed. I posted [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80857/my-process-was-killed-but-i-cannot-understand-the-kernel-notice) on unix/linux stackexchange and the answer to it partially helps me. The problem is that when I disable the serial port SAK using

```
 setserial /dev/ttyS0 ^sak
```

at system startup, when I later open the port using userspace API C code the serial port is opened with the SAK option again (I have verified this by disabling SAK, starting up my application, checking `setserial` again only to find SAK set once more). Basically, I need to know what flags I need to set in my `termios` struct that I pass to `tcsetattr()` when I am configuring the serial port. Currently my code that opens the serial is as follows:

```
int current_fd = open(strfile.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
termios new_settings;
tcgetattr(current_fd, &old_options);
tcgetattr(current_fd, &new_settings);

new_settings.c_cflag = 0;
new_settings.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD | CS8);
new_settings.c_lflag = 0;
new_settings.c_oflag = 0;
new_settings.c_oflag |= (ONOCR | ONLRET);  
new_settings.c_iflag = 0;
new_settings.c_iflag |= (IGNBRK | IGNPAR | IGNCR);    
tcsetattr(current_fd, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
```

I have read through all of the `termios` man pages and I cannot see anything that refers to the SAK - the only relevent thing is the `IGNBRK` setting which I have set. Is there anything I can do to disable the SAK setting on the serial port via the userspace API?

Comment: My first suggestion to you would be to always base your new termios flags on the old ones (ie. always AND out the things you're changing, and OR in the new flags). This would mean that any flags unknown to your code wouldn't be affected by your changes.

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes that is good advice and I do usually do this. In this case I just wanted to illustrate concisely what flags I am setting. I do always store the original settings though and reset them when the program closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually been able to do this using the `serial_struct` struct and `ASYNC_SAK` flag using `ioctl()` as follows

```
serial_struct s_serial;
memset(&s_serial,0,sizeof(s_serial));
ioctl(current_fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &s_serial);
s_serial.flags &= ~ASYNC_SAK;  
ioctl(current_fd, TIOCSSERIAL, &s_serial);
```

I am still at a loss as to why opening the serial port had overridden the `sak` flag that I had previously set using `setserial()` but adding the code above before I set the `termios` options has resolved the issue and the `sak` flag remains disabled.